# How to use IOS third party keyboards in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter

I have the flutter application is in production  and today we received a request from users to technical support that third-party keyboards in our application cannot  be use. Only in our app. Is there any way to solve this? Help, pls

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It should be enabled by default. Have you tested and reproduced this issue yourself? It might just be an issue with their phone.